# How to pass parameter from recipe to deploy callback (before_migrate.rb, before_symlink.rb, etc) in Chef

Tags: deployment, chef-infra

I have variable defined in recipe (not a node attribute), how am I able to pass value of this variable to callback?

I know that callback have release_path, and new_resource. Can I pass another variable to deploy callback?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest route is to build the full command, including variables inside your recipe, and then pass that command into the deploy resource.

Comment: For example: look at the examples in the documentation? https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html